# How can I disable model compatibility checking in Entity Framework 4.3?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I'm working with EF 4.3 and have a context which needs to talk to a database which was generated by another library using EF Code First 4.3.  The context is throwing an exception stating

> The model backing the 'Context' context has changed since the
>       database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update 
>       the database

In EF 4.1 this could be diabled by removing the `IncludeMetadataConvention` from the ModelBuilder.  However, in 4.3 this convention has been deprecated and no longer has an effect.

How can I have an EF 4.3 context talk to an EF 4.3-generated database *built by a different context*?  The only option I've found (which is far from ideal) is to delete the metadata table, thereby causing *both* contexts to assume the database was not build by EF.

**PS:** I know this scenario is likely to raise questions about *why* I need to do this; I know it's far from ideal, but rest assured it's a problem I need to solve and have limited options to work with laterally.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Setting the initializer to `null` will skip the model compatibility check.

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

Comment: Where do you put this?

Comment: A static constructor on your context seems to work pretty well for most applications.

Comment: @deepakgates I have it in my Context constructor.

Comment: Add `using System.Data.Entity` if this line shows error.

Comment: If you find this isn't working as expected then check the EF section of your config file. Make sure your context has disableDatabaseInitialization="true". I lost far too many hours to this and no one mentions it in their answers on here. More info on this setting can be found on the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606

Answer (score 15):

For EF 4.3 or higher

```
Database.SetInitializer<MLTServerWatcherContext>(null);
```

Or if using older version of EF

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
```

(I know he said he are using EF 4.3, but i think it's good to show this option too)