# Get Table type when you have different table name from datacontext

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext

We can get table name if we have table `type`. like here

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();
var tableName = dc.Mapping.GetTable(type).TableName.ToString();
```

In my case I have table name and wants to get table type. but how?

**Note**: Table name and type are different (in spelling) in my `DataContext` case. So i can't convert table name to type like below.

```
Type tableType = Type.GetType("dbo." + tableName);
```

Comment: I don't even know how you got the table name to be different from the data type.  Didn't know that was possible

Comment: `DataContext` take singular table type. Like if you have table name `Companies` then `DataContext` take `Company` table type. So both are different in spelling.

Comment: oh yeah okay.  I know what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

I assume you found a solution, but if not please have me elaborate.

I just wanted to note that I ended up using DbContext (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx) instead of DataContext.  I tried creating a derived class to basically rename it, but that didn't work.  DataContext needed to have its hand held with all the attribute metadata ([Column], for example).  If I bothered to do this I might as well re-code the models (which is bad, since it's code duplication).

In my case, my database was being generated/managed by an ASP.NET Web API project.  I shared my models and database with a separate (and eventually independent) class library.  This can cause some problems so make sure to disable model compatibility checking: [How can I disable model compatibility checking in Entity Framework 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623260/how-can-i-disable-model-compatibility-checking-in-entity-framework-4-3).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var db = new DataContext();
    var tables = db.Mapping.GetTables();
    var tableTypeName = tables.Where(r => r.TableName == "yourTableName").Select(r => r.RowType.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```