# Entity Framework COde FIrst migration existing table

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a (strange) situation.
I am using Entity Framework Code First but I have to attach to an existing Database.

I do not have to map every single table of the database in my object model. So I would like to migrate single Tables, whenever I need it. 
I try to explain better. My database have about 100 tables, but I need to map in my model just 3 or 4. I have created my classes in c# and now I would like to map this classes with the tables I need.

Is it possible to do it? Do I have to do a migration?

**UPDATE**
Here my class:

```
public class PricePlan
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Double ActivationPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Here the context:

```
public class PublicAreaContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<PricePlan> PricePlans { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PricePlan>()
            .HasKey(pp => new { pp.Id });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Here the table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PricePlan](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ActivationPrice] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    ... //Other columns
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Price_Plans] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2):

possible: yes

migration: no. If you need migration you may have problem as in this case you haven't the __migrationHistory table (as the db is "existing" by opposite to "created by EF").

But the answer is definitively yes.

Create your classes, create a DbContext comprising DbSet, "et voilà".

Comment: It's not enough... When I try to do an insert to the table of database, I obtain this message: `The model backing the 'PublicAreaContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database`.. Give me 2 minutes and I update the question

Comment: do you have a __migrationHistory table in your database ?

Comment: that means that the database is not "existing". Don't you have access to the context class corresponding to the Db ? Otherwise you may use `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623260/how-can-i-disable-model-compatibility-checking-in-entity-framework-4-3

Comment: Strange, I have solved deleting the `__migrationHistory` and launching the following command: `Update-Database -verbose -StartUpProjectName MyProject` int the `Package Manager Console`

Comment: Not strange: DANGEROUS. There is an historical context accessing the database (the one which created the __migrationHistory table). Now this context, and the app depending on it may become instable.